# Not Using com.sun Package

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Recently I was working on some migration stuff. I was searching some stuff on this site. I came across a post saying com.sun package is not advisable for use. But the application that I am working on, is using the packages in quite a few places. Especially these classes:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.handler.SOAPMessageContextImpl
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties
```

I was looking for some alternatives. Since I am on the migration process, might as well move it to something that is a "better practice"

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you should not use internal classes which might disappear on any future release of JAVA.

Comment: Yes, but what do i replace the classes with?